# How to append numbers only on duplicates sequence names?

Tags: fasta, text

I have a reference database with contains 100s of sequences in fasta format. Some of these sequences have duplicate names like so:

```
>1_uniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_anotherUniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_duplicateName
atgc
>1_duplicateName
atgc
```

Is is possible to run through a large file like this and change the names of only the duplicates?

```
>1_uniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_anotherUniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_duplicateName_1
atgc
>1_duplicateName_2
atgc
```

Comment: Do you want to only change the names of the duplicates, I mean of the second, third etc seqs with the same name or also of the 1st as you have done? I mean, do you really need `duplicate_1`, `duplicate_2` or is `duplicate`, `duplicate_1` enough? The latter is far simpler since the former will require you to read the file twice.

Comment: Cool. Id prefer the `duplicate_1 duplicate_2`format but if it is much more complex then I am fine with the `duplicate duplicate_1`format.

Comment: @AudileF: I'm having a hard time coming up with a good reason why I would want the first duplicate to be changed as well.  Can you give us a bit more insight into the reason for this request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, this little Perl snippet should do it:

```
$ perl -pe 's/$/_$seen{$_}/ if ++$seen{$_}>1 and /^>/; ' file.fa 
>1_uniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_anotherUniqueGeneName
atgc_2
>1_duplicateName
atgc_3
>1_duplicateName_2
atgc_4
```

Or, to make the changes in the original file, use `-i`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/$/_$seen{$_}/ if ++$seen{$_}>1 and /^>/; ' file.fa
```

Note that the first occurrence of a duplicate name isn't changed, the second will become `_2`, the third `_3` etc.

#### Explanation

- `perl -pe` : **p**rint each input line after applying the script given by `-e` to it.
- `++$seen{$_}>1` : increment the current value stored in the hash `%seen` for this line (`$_`) by 1 and compare it to `1`.
- `s/$/_$seen{$_}/ if ++$seen{$_}>1 and /^>/` : if the current line starts with a `>` and the  value stored in the hash `%seen` for this line is greater than 1 (if this isn't the first time we see this line), replace the end of the line (`$`) with a `_` and the current value in the hash

---

Alternatively, here's the same idea in `awk`:

```
$ awk '(/^>/ && s[$0]++){$0=$0"_"s[$0]}1;' file.fa 
>1_uniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_anotherUniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_duplicateName
atgc
>1_duplicateName_2
atgc
```

To make the changes in the original file (assuming you are using GNU `awk` which is the default on most Linux versions), use `-i inplace`:

```
awk -iinplace '(/^>/ && s[$0]++){$0=$0"_"s[$0]}1;' file.fa
```

#### Explanation

In awk, the special variable `$0` is the current line.

- `(/^>/ && s[$0]++)` : if this line starts with a `>` and incrementing the value stored in the array `s` for this line by 1 evaluates to true (is greater than 0).
- `$0=$0"_"s[$0]` :  make the current line be itself with a `_` and the value from `s` appended.
- `1;` : this is just shorthand for "print this line". If an expression evaluates to true, awk will print the current line. Since `1` is always true, this will print every line.

---

If you want all of the duplicates to be marked, you need to read the file twice. Once to collect the names and a second to mark them:

```
$ awk '{
    if (NR==FNR){
        if(/^>/){
            s[$0]++
        }
        next;
    }
    if(/^>/){
        k[$0]++;
        if(s[$0]>1){
            $0=$0"_"k[$0]
        }
    }
    print
}' file.fa file.fa
>1_uniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_anotherUniqueGeneName
atgc
>1_duplicateName_1
atgc
>1_duplicateName_2
atgc
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: note that all of these approaches assume you don't already have sequence names ending with `_N` where `N` is a number. If your input file has 2 sequences called `foo` and one called `foo_2`, then you will end up with two `foo_2`:

```
$ cat test.fa
>foo_2
actg
>foo
actg
>foo
actg
$ perl -pe 's/$/_$seen{$_}/ if ++$seen{$_}>1 and /^>/; ' test.fa 
>foo_2
actg
>foo
actg
>foo_2
actg
```

If this can be an issue for you, use one of the more sophisticated approaches suggested by the other answers.

Comment: In the `awk` example I worry that duplicate IDs could be created if you have contigs like `>foo` and `>foo_1` in the original file. `foo_1` wouldn't be in `s`, but might already have been printed out if `foo` had already been encountered.

Comment: @DevonRyan ah, yes that's a very valid point. Not just the awk one either, all approaches here break if a duplicate sequence already exists with a `_N`. In that case, the extra verbiage added by python is actually worth it :P. I added a disclaimer, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

And here’s a solution using R (with the Bioconductor):

```r
fa = ShortRead::readFasta(infile)
ids = as.character(ShortRead::id(fa))
fa@id = Biostrings::BStringSet(make.unique(ids, sep = '_'))
ShortRead::writeFasta(fa, outfile)
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure, using biopython:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Bio import SeqIO

records = set()
of = open("output.fa", "w")
for record in SeqIO.parse("foo.fa", "fasta"):
    ID = record.id
    num = 1
    while ID in records:
        ID = "{}_{}".format(record.id, num)
        num += 1
    records.add(ID)
    record.id = ID
    record.name = ID
    record.description = ID
    SeqIO.write(record, of, "fasta")
of.close()
```

Change `output.fa` and `foo.fa`. One doesn't need to explicitly change the `.name` and `.description`, but that's handy to prevent the original ID from not appearing still (after a space).

## Explanation

- `records = set()` This will create a lookup table of all IDs **written**
- `for record in SeqIO.parse("foo.fa", "fasta"):` Open `foo.fa` as a fasta file and iterate over the **entries** in it. These are objects with an ID, name, description, and sequence attribute (the name and description are the same as the ID if not present).
- `ID = record.id` [Memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the entry ID (e.g., `1_duplicateName`)
- `while ID in records:` As long as the ID has already been seen, keep looping.
- `ID = "{}_{}".format(record.id, num)` Start adding increasing numbers after the ID, such as `1_duplicateName_1` and `1_duplicateName_2`. This will continue until the ID has not been seen.
- `records.add(ID)` Add the unseen ID to the set.
- `record.id = ID` Update the ID, the `.name` and `.description` are the same. If you don't do that, then you get output like `>1_duplicateName_1 1_duplicateName`. That's not really a problem, but it's excessive.
- `SeqIO.write(record, of, "fasta")` Write the record to the output file in fasta format.

A benefit of biopython is the easy ability to change formats, so instead of fasta one could have substituted Genbank or another format if needed.